# Enable access for @RestController using spring security

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a project which is implemented using spring security basic auth. There are four access roles mapped. `"ADMIN"` is mapped to `"/admin/**"`

I am able to login and access all the html resources in the `WebContent/admin` folder. Post that I created some services using `@RestController` `@RequestMapping("/admin/users")`

The problem is I am unable to access any restful services. Error is `404`. All the restful service class is present in the war file. I am sure there are some configuration problem. Any idea on it?

My code spinet:

SecurityConfig .java

```
package com.dev.portal.mvc.configs;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.dev.portal.constants.UserRoles;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] allRoles = { UserRoles.ADMIN, UserRoles.ORG_ADMIN, UserRoles.CATALOG_ADMIN, UserRoles.DEVELOPER };
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole(allRoles)
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(UserRoles.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/org_admin/**").hasRole(UserRoles.ORG_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/catalog_admin/**").hasRole(UserRoles.CATALOG_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/developer/**").hasRole(UserRoles.DEVELOPER)
            .and().formLogin().successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

MvcConfig.java

```
package com.dev.portal.mvc.configs;
import static com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.builder;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

import com.dev.portal.commons.CertificateHelper;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

@PropertySource({ "classpath:mongodb.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dev.portal.services.orgadmin")
public class MvcConfig {

    private @Value("${db.ip}") String db_ip;
    private @Value("${db.port}") String db_port;
    private @Value("${db.name}") String db_name;
    private @Value("${db.user}") String db_user;
    private @Value("${db.password}") String db_password;
    private @Value("${db.admin}") String db_admin;

    @Bean
    public CustomSuccessHandler getCustomSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AppUserDetailsService getAppUserDetailsService() {
        return new AppUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
        MongoClient mongoClient =
                new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(db_ip, Integer.parseInt(db_port)),
                        Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(db_user, db_admin,
                                db_password.toCharArray())),
                        builder().sslEnabled(true).socketFactory(CertificateHelper.validateCert(db_ip))
                                .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).build());
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, db_name));
    }

}
```

UserModelService.java

```
package com.dev.portal.services.orgadmin;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.dev.portal.dao.client.UserAuthDaoClient;
import com.dev.portal.models.UserAuthModel;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/org_admin/user")
public class UserModelService {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    UserAuthDaoClient userAuthDaoClient = new UserAuthDaoClient(mongoTemplate);

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public UserAuthModel getUserAuthModelByUsername(@RequestParam String username) {
        return userAuthDaoClient.getUserAuthModelByUsername(username);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public UserAuthModel saveOrUpdateUserAuthModel(@RequestBody UserAuthModel userAuthModel) {
        return userAuthDaoClient.saveOrUpdateUserAuthModel(userAuthModel);
    }

}
```

WebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.dev.portal.mvc.configs;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class WebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public WebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(MvcConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified `MvcConfig.java` and `WebApplicationInitializer.java` as below and it stated working. I am still finding another way as I am using extend of deprecated class.

MvcConfig.java

```
package com.dev.portal.mvc.configs;

import static com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.builder;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.dev.portal.commons.CertificateHelper;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({ "classpath:mongodb.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dev.portal.services.**")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private @Value("${db.ip}") String db_ip;
    private @Value("${db.port}") String db_port;
    private @Value("${db.name}") String db_name;
    private @Value("${db.user}") String db_user;
    private @Value("${db.password}") String db_password;
    private @Value("${db.admin}") String db_admin;

    @Bean
    public CustomSuccessHandler getCustomSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AppUserDetailsService getAppUserDetailsService() {
        return new AppUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
        MongoClient mongoClient =
                new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(db_ip, Integer.parseInt(db_port)),
                        Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(db_user, db_admin,
                                db_password.toCharArray())),
                        builder().sslEnabled(true).socketFactory(CertificateHelper.validateCert(db_ip))
                                .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).build());
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, db_name));
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

WebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.dev.portal.mvc.configs;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public WebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(MvcConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.addListener(new net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener());
        servletContext.addFilter("CorsFilter", CORSFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dev-portal-dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }

}
```

CORSFilter.java

```
package com.dev.portal.mvc.configs;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```